# jQuery, Rails and Ajax POST to database

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, http

I wanted to do a POST request to the 'create' route, generated through scaffolding.
The controller name is 'Translation' and the create route is '/translation'. In order to do that I created an ajax request with jQuery. My request looks like that -

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/translations",
        data: ?,
        success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
        }
});
```

I want the data to include my paramaters, so that the translation generated will have these values. The translation's paramaters are 'source' and 'output'. 
Generated by scaffolding, the translation controller 'create' method looks like that -

```
  def create
    @translation = Translation.new(params[:translation])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @translation.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@translation, :notice => 'Translation was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @translation, :status => :created, :location => @translation }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @translation.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I tried to insert different values to the data, yet it doesn't apply them. A new translation is created, but with no parameters.
These are the data parameters I tried to insert so far in order to make the 'output' value 'hello' -

```
data: {'source':'hello'}
data: "source=hello"
data: {translations:{'source':'hello'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
data = { translation : { source : 'hello' } }
```

But... are you using form helpers? it's easier to get this field correctly formatted.

Comment: I know how to do it with rails forms, but I still wanted to it with jQuery. I was lazy translating my javascript functions to ruby, which costed me alot of time. Anyway, It works, thanks :)